# Type declaration equivalence in C: are these types identical technically, or just pragmatically identical?

Tags: c, type-declaration

I've been learning C, and there's something about type declarations that still isn't clear to me, and I haven't found a great answer yet. From what I'm seeing, the exact ordering of the type and modifiers doesn't seem all that important from a practical, pragmatic standpoint. For example, these lines below are all essentially equivalent (right?):

```
const int * np;
int const * np;
int * const np;
```

My question is, are these actually *completely* equivalent in the eyes of (say) the compiler, and/or are there some differences in them that could become important in some case(s)?

In reading through other's code, I find that there is a lot of variation in how people prefer to do these declarations, and I'm just trying to be sure I'm not missing something important.

Comment: Seems my question is a duplicate. I should say I couldn't find that answer using Google or SO's own search bar, so hopefully my question is a little more search friendly and will lead others to those other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two are the same, but the third is not.

In the first two cases, `np` is a pointer to a `const int`.  So you can change `np` but not `*np`.

In the third case, `np` is a `const` pointer to `int`.  So `np` cannot be changed but `*np` can.